# Receiving an XML array over REST into MULE ESB flow

Tags: java, xml, arrays, mule, esb

Not sure if I'm going down the wrong path, but I can't get it to work anyway.

I'm trying to receive an XML message through a REST endpoint into a Mule flow and then convert that XML into a POJO so that I can do stuff with it. The XML can have a list of items in it similar to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Commission>
    <commissionRecords>
        <commissionRecord>
            <entityNumber>
                768768
            </entityNumber> 
        <commissionRecord>
        <commissionRecord>
            <entityNumber>
                127698
            </entityNumber> 
        <commissionRecord>
    </commissionRecords>
</Commission>
```

I have been successful in receiving a simple class with just one value, but so far whenever I send an array I get nothing coming through. I've been playing with the `javax.xml.annotations` on the classes, but haven't come up with the correct ones.

Currently classes look like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Commission {
 @XmlElement(name="commissionRecord")
 protected CommissionRecord[] commissionRecords;

 //public getter and setters without annotations
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class CommissionRecord {
 protected int entityNumber;

 //public getter and setters without annotations
}
```

And my flow looks like:

[image: Mule ESB flow]

When I run this I get an empty message in the Echo and the Logger (which just logs the message payload) I get NullPayload.

If I leave everything else the same, but reduce my message to a single field. Then it works fine.

Are my annotations incorrect? Am I following the completely wrong method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go schema first instead of trying to manually tweak a JAXB-annotated class into submission.

- Create an XSD for your message,
- Generate the JAXB-annotated class from it,
- Profit.